# Abstract Cosets Dihedral

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider $D_8$ = {$1,r,r^2,r^3, b,br,br^2,br^3$} and the subgroups $H$ = $<r^2>$ and $K$=$<b>$ of $D_8$.

List all the left cosets of $ H$ in $ D_8 $.

I have:

1$\cdot$$H$ = $r^2$$H$ = {1,$r^2$}

$r$$H$ = $r^3$$H$ = {$r$,$r^3$}

$b$$H$ = $b$$r^2$$H$ = {$b$,$br^2$}

$b$$r$$H$ = $b$$r^3$$H$ = {$br$,$br^3$}

Need to show that $D_8$/$H$ $\approxeq$ $HK$.

Can someone please help?

Comment: I think you mean $bH = br^2H = \{b,br^2\}$ on your third line.

Comment: @AlexP.yeah your'e right, thanks.

Comment: Can those voting to close please explain *why*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So $HK = \{1,r^2,b,br^2\}$, and $D_8/H = \{\{1,r^2\},\{r,r^3\},\{b,br^2\},\{br,br^3\}\}$.

**Hint**: Can you show that both are isomorphic to the [Klein four-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein_four-group)?